# Doom Emacs kill-word binding

Tags: key-bindings, doom

My keybindings say I can hit `C-<delete>` to run `kill-word`.  This does not seem to work for me.  When I hit `C-<delete>` it only delete a single character to the right of my cursor.  How can I fix it so it removes the whole word?  `kill-word` works as expected when I do `M-x kill-word`.

Comment: Can't check this just yet since I'm still on the bus, but I checked my termux version of doom and `M-d` seems to run `kill-word` too. Does that keybind work for you, or are both of them not working?

Comment: Just tried it on doom commit 8f6b045df and `C-<delete>` seems to invoke `kill-word` like it's supposed to. Could you try running `SPC h k C-<delete>` (`helpful-key C-<delete>`) and see what command is being invoked?

Comment: `SPC h k M-d` says `evil-multiedit-match-symbol-and-next` is being ran.

Comment: `SPC h k C-<delete>` says `evil-delete-char` is being ran.

Comment: The `M-d` makes sense if you have the `multi-cursor` package enabled (I do as well, so M-d returns that command for me too). That `C-<delete>` seems strange because `evil-delete-char` is run when `<deletechar>` (which I believe is the delete key) is pressed. That makes me suspect that your doom isn't capturing that you pressed Control or that the keymap is being overwritten by a package. Could you run `SPC h f kill-word` and report back what the Keymaps section says in your Helpful menu? (for reference, I have 3 bindings: `esc-map d`, `global-map C-<delete>`, and `global-map M-d`)

Comment: Also, try running `doom/sandbox` and experimenting with the sandboxes to isolate the problem. I would recommend starting with the vanilla doom sandbox to see if the problem is in a package. If that works, then try the doom + modules - private config sandbox to see if the problem could be with your config files.

Comment: When I run `SPC h f kill-word` I only see one entry: `kill-word (C-<delete>)`.  Inside the entry it says `C-<delete>` belongs to `global-map`, there's no mention of `evil-delete-char`.